# C: What does (exp1)? (exp2)? (exp3) : (exp4) : (exp5) operator do?

Tags: c, operators

I saw lines of C that looked like thi:

```
rFrameL    = block_a.available    ?
    img->mb_data[block_a.mb_addr].mb_field ?
    refPic[list][block_a.pos_y][block_a.pos_x]:
    refPic[list][block_a.pos_y][block_a.pos_x] * 2:
    -1;
```

It seems like nested *if and else* expression but I do not know how it exactly works. is (exp3) returned when (exp1) is true?
 is (exp4) returned when (exp2) returned? 
is(exp5) returned when (exp1) and (exp2) are false?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `? :` conditional operator in general? Are you just asking what happens when you use it multiple times in the same expression?

Comment: Yes I know what ? : operator does but I do not know what happens when I use it multiple times in the same expression.

Comment: [C operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With parenthesis around implicit order of operations:

```
rFrameL    = block_a.available    ?
    (img->mb_data[block_a.mb_addr].mb_field ?
       refPic[list][block_a.pos_y][block_a.pos_x]:
       refPic[list][block_a.pos_y][block_a.pos_x] * 2):
    -1;
```

Given `a?b:c`, this means "does a evaluate to true, if yes then evaluate b, otherwise evaluate c".  In the above expression, `b` is being evaluated when a `?` is encountered, so it starts a new ternary operation.  The first `:` that is encountered matches up with the second `?`, then the second `:` ends evaluation of `b`.

Comment: when (exp2) is true, (exp3) is returns. when (exp2) is false, (exp4) returns. when (exp1) is true, it returns the result from expression of (exp2) and (exp3). and (exp1) is false, it returns -1. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is a nested if-else statement in the ternary operator format.
The '?' refers to 'if' which is solved with the answer in the ':'

In simple, the following code is similar to the ternary operator format :

```
if (exp1)
{
  if(exp2)
  {
    if(exp3)
    {
      exp4;
    }
    exp5;
  }
  exp6;
}
```